# How to use wildcards in Spring MVC servlet mapping URLs?

Tags: spring-mvc

I've got a controller set up in my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/console/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And a matching bean defined in controller-servlet.xml:

```
<bean name="/console/index" class="com.package.OverviewController"/>
```

Which works correctly - when I get "/appName/console/index" it behaves as I expect. But when I change web.xml to this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/console/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It no longer functions, giving me the following exception:

```
WARN (org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound) - No mapping for [/appName/console/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'controller'
```

So my question is how do I use wildcards in the servlet mappings, so that different URLs all go through the single DispatcherServlet but may go to one of several controller beans?

FYI: I'm stuck on Spring 2.0, as it's an established application used in government.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use wildcards in `<url-pattern>`, controller names by default correspond to wildcard part of the pattern.

So, you can either rename your controller to `/index`, or set the `alwaysUseFullPath` property of your `HandlerMapping` to `true`.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction (coincidence or not) to solve my related issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/78163469/714112