# No mapping found in DispatcherServlet without using extension

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am receiving the message "The requested resource () is not available." when going to a url that I have mapped using DispatcherServlet.  It previously worked when I had the mapping setup to use a .do extension, but when I map without an extension it doesn't work.

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class WodServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private WodService wodService;

    @RequestMapping("/json/wod")
    @ResponseBody
    public Word getWord(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return wodService.getWordOfTheDay();
    }
}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="foobar.controller" />

<!-- View Resolvers -->

<bean id="defaultViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Services</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:commonBeans.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/json/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

If I have the mapping set to *.do and the RequestMapping set to wod.do it works fine.

EDIT:

In the logs, when I go to that URL it shows the message

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/foobar/json/wod] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

EDIT 2: I added the alwaysUseFullPath to the handler:

```
<bean id="annotationHandlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />  
</bean>
```

Comment: So I use Spring a lot and the reason you are getting the resource not available message is because your servlet probably crashed. I would check the error logs and see what caused it. To get it back online, simply redeploy the war and you should be able to access it again. Hope that helps.

Comment: It definitely hasn't crashed.  See my edit.

Comment: What URL are you putting into your browser? When you load up a spring servlet when  you go to hostname:port/dispatcher/ you should get a page telling you it worked if you are using standard spring set ups. These servlet would then be catching all requests to  hostname:port/dispatcher/json/* .

Comment: The URL I've mostly tried (assuming my context is foobar) is hostname:port/foobar/json/wod .  I've also tried what you suggested among others - it worked fine when I used a .do extension and went to /foobar/json/wod.do

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397531/how-to-use-wildcards-in-spring-mvc-servlet-mapping-urls

Comment: I tried adding the alwaysUseFullPath, but it STILL doesn't work.. argghh...

Comment: @acvcu: Have you tried to remove `/json` from `@RequestMapping`?

Comment: I also tried using <url-pattern>/json/</url-pattern> and it still doesn't work... no one has a clue what could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to the way my apache redirect was setup.